# is every bijective function a permutation?

Tags: functions, permutations

Can I call a continuous bijective function a permutation?

For example the function, $$f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad f(x)=2x+1$$

maps the set of real numbers to itself and it's bijective. So is it a permutation? Or are permutations defined only on finite sets?

Comment: You can permuted countably infinite sets with a bijection to $\mathbb N$

Comment: See also [permutations of totally ordered sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Comment: In Maths, you can call anything however you like. Unlike Physics or Chemistry, there is no organization or standard for Maths nomenclature or notation. Nevertheless, the word 'permutation' is more often used to bijections from a finite set to itself.

Comment: Even if @ajotatxe is right, it's always nice to reread what Serge Lang writes: "Let S be a set. A bijective mapping $f:S\to S$ of $S$ with itself is called a "permutation" of $S$."(Undergraduate Algebra, Springer, p. 30)

Answer (score 2):

By definition a permutation is a bijection of a set onto itself. Such definition is interesting because for finite sets permutations form a group structure: the $\textbf{Group of Permutation}$, usually written as $S_n$ where $n$ is the number of elements we are permutating. In algebra, specifically in group theory and Galois theory such structure is very important if not central at all, and thus it makes sense to define it and study it.

For (non countably) infinite set you may define it in the same fashion: the bijections of any set always form a group under composition. You may think of such maps as "infinite reordering" but I'm not sure if such thing is of any help.